# Documents only added to Firestore while I'm debugging my program

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am creating a simple java server for my firestore database. The problem is that when I run my application, nothing is added to the collection. When I debug and step through my program, then I can see that the document was successfully added.

I tried to create separate methods for adding the documents to firestore but this did not solve it. I copied the code to add documents directly from the Firestore Documentation and like I said, the code works but only when I'm stepping through the app in debug mode.

```
    Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();        
    data.put("random",-1);

    ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = db.collection("Confirm").document("randomdoc").set(data);
```

Comment: Firestore APIs that return an ApiFuture are all asynchronous and multithreaded on Java.  Those methods return immediately.  Your use of the debugger is likely changing the way the threads in your app are interacting.  The code you're showing here isn't enough to see what those interactions might be.

Comment: pretty much the whole code of my app, am I supposed to define the threads?

Comment: For the purpose of getting questions answered on Stack Overflow, you should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: You should halt your program/JVM until the `ApiFuture` instances come to a completion. Otherwise the JVM will exit before your code gets a chance to write out any data to Firestore. When you're debugging, you're introducing enough delay to the program, and the writes are completed successfully.